# How to Enable/Disable Three- and four-finger touch gestures using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Just want to ask if is there any C# code to enable/disable the Three- and four-finger touch gestures in Windows. Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Touch > Three- and four-finger touch gestures I have some options related to registry modification:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
```

three-and four-finger touch gestures to on:
"TouchGestureSetting"=dword:00000001

Three four-finger touch gestures to off:
"TouchGestureSetting"=dword:00000000

But after modification of this need to restart the machine. I want to enable or disable this option without restarting the machine.
[Setting UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHeiP.png)

```
RegistryKey regHKCUKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"ControlPanel\Desktop",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
 if (regHKCUKey != null)
 {
     var regKey = regHKCUKey.GetValue("TouchGestureSetting").ToString();
     if (regKey == "1")
     {
         regHKCUKey.SetValue("TouchGestureSetting ", "0",RegistryValueKind.DWord);
     }
     regHKCUKey.Flush();
     regHKCUKey.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Maybe restart `explorer.exe`

Comment: No Charlieface.
After restarting the explorer.exe, it does not reflect any change.

Comment: Do you need to restart the machine if you were to, for example, use Powershell to enable or disable the three/four-fingers gesture?